# Unity rigidbody pushed away on boxcollider2d edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My two vertical raycast at the feet check if the player is on the ground. The others check if the player collides in a specific direction. My problem is when the player hits the ground on the edge, he will first be on the ground for a very short time and then just fall. Any ideas how I can fix that he stays on the edge and not just fall? I tested it by moving the player on the edge and change its y axis higher. He then just be on the ground for a very short time and slides to the sides. The velocity changes to zero when the player hits the ground. He doesnt slide down when i just put him there without height.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by decreasing fixed timestep and maximum allowed timestep in the project settings.